# strace -f strace /bin/ls failed with PTRACE_TRACEME EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: permissions, strace

When I run

```
strace -f strace /bin/ls
```

to know how strace work it failed with

```
ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

even with root account.

It there any solution for this?

Answer (score 19):

#### Docker

When running `strace` within Docker container, to enable [`ptrace`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace), run with `SYS_PTRACE` param:

```
docker run -it --cap-add SYS_PTRACE ubuntu
```

See: [Running Strace in Docker](http://blog.johngoulah.com/2016/03/running-strace-in-docker/).

Answer (score 3):

ptrace system call is limited only one tracing application per process.

man ptrace:

> ```
>   EPERM  The  specified  process cannot be traced.  This could be because the tracer has insuffi‐
>          cient privileges (the required capability  is  CAP_SYS_PTRACE);  unprivileged  processes
>          cannot  trace  processes  that  they  cannot  send signals to or those running set-user-
>          ID/set-group-ID programs, for obvious reasons.  Alternatively, the process  may  already
>          be being traced, or (on kernels before 2.6.26) be init(1) (PID 1).
> ```

This means only a debug application can attach to same process. When you done strace -f you tell it to attach all process started by program debugged. In your case strace call fork to create a new process and setups the new process for debugging using ptrace system call. Then it calls exec with parameters you provide to the call. This then start strace again which tries to do fork and ptrace again. But the second ptrace fails with EPERM because first strace has already attached to the process.

Running first strace without -f parameter allows you to trace the first thread from second strace while second strace is tracing the ls.

```
strace strace -f ls
```

There is -b to detach from lwp when a specific syscall is made but it only supports execve. If there was a ptrace call support it  would be perfect. That means strace either needs a small patch to support ptrace call.

Alternative potential hacks include preloaded library which implements detaching with some trickery.

Better alternative would be using tracing tool systemtap or trace-cmd which can use kernel provided tracing infrastructure instead of ptrace.

Answer (score 2):

I mention this and more helpful tips in a recent [blog post about strace](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/11/15/strace-cheat-sheet/).

You need to enable support for gdb, strace, and similar tools to attach to processes on the system.

You can do this temporarily by running command to set a setting proc:

`sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope'`

You can persist that setting between system reboots by modifying `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` and setting `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0`.

If your system does not have `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf`, you can modify `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0`.

Comment: I got same error after  `cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` 0. 
pid 13953] ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Comment: I get the error although I'm using root and `cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` yields 0. The problem may me due to the fact that the process runs inside a docker container. Any experience with this?